# Railcasts 340 - Datatables (not working for me)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I just started watching the beginning of this tutorial about implementing datatables within the Ruby on Rails application. I've followed the first few steps which are to only add the gems in the Gemfile, add the necessary content in the javascript and css file, and then add the ID attribute to the table. That should at the very least get things working. Doesn't work for me though

Here's the files that the Railcasts demo simply modified to get a very basic datatable working:

```
    #Gemfile
    ...
    gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'
    gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
    gem 'will_paginate'
```

.

```
#application.css
/*

 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
 */
```

.

```
#assets/javascript/products.js
jQuery ->
    $('#products').dataTable()
```

.

```
#views/products.html.erb
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-responsive" id="products">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center"><%= check_box_tag "selectAll", "SelectAll" %></th>
      <th class="text-center">Product</th>
      <th colspan="3" class="text-center">Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center"><%= check_box_tag "product_ids[]", product.id %></td>
      <td class="text-center"><%= product.id %></td>
      <td class="text-center"><%= link_to "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span>".html_safe, "#", class: "btn btn-xs btn-primary" %>
      <%= link_to "<span class=' glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span>".html_safe, "#", method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn btn-xs btn-danger" %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<%= render 'edit_multiple' %>
<% end %>
```

I know the demo goes into much further than this, but this is what he did to get it working at the minimum. Any ideas?

Comment: No one has a single clue? I've even downloaded the sample app provided by them and not even that works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust where `require dataTables/jquery.dataTables` sits.  It should look like this.

```
*= require_self
*= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
*= require_tree .
```

Also, if that doesn't work you should post the application.js file and make sure you added it there.

```
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require_tree .
```

Hope this helps.